# Finding Copula from bivariate CDF

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

For the joint CDF:
[image]

I want to show that it has copula given by:
$$
C(a,b) = \frac{ab}{a+b-ab}
$$

I've found the marginal distribution functions as:
$$
F_X(x) = \frac{x+1}{2} \mathbb{I}_{x \in [-1,1]} + \mathbb{I}_{x>1} ,  \quad 
F_Y(y) =(e^y -1) \mathbb{I}_{y \in [0,\log 2]} + \mathbb{I}_{y>\log 2}
$$
and so, we have inverse DF's:
$$
F^{-1}_X(a) = 2a-1,  \quad 
F^{-1}_Y(b) = \log(1+b)
$$
Then, by Sklar's Theorem:
\begin{align}
C(a,b) & = F(F^{-1}_X(a), F^{-1}_Y(b))\\
&= \frac{ab}{a+b}
\end{align}

is there a typo in the question, or am I missing something?

**Update**
$F_y(y) = \lim_{x \to 1} F_{X,Y} = 1-e^{-y}$
and now the result follows easily.

Comment: Are you sure of your $F_Y$?

Comment: @Etienne with no further info how can we tell whether there is a right extreme of $x$? What I was doing was taking $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x,y)$, after your suggestion i took $x \to 1$ which seemed intuitively correct, but in general how do you deduce it?

Comment: To take the limit as $x\to\infty$ was the correct thing to do; but this does not seem to give what you wrote in your post.

Comment: @Etienne oh, silly mistake..thanks